# How can I test properties of a symbol from the string name without the symbol completely evaluating

Tags: evaluation, symbols, expression-test

Suppose I have a few symbols, one of which has a value:

```
{abc1, abc2 = 5, abc3};
```

I can use `Names` to get the list of names, as strings:

```
InputForm[names = Names["Global`abc*"]]
(* {"abc1", "abc2", "abc3"} *)
```

Now I want to find which symbols have values.  This fails, because `ValueQ` expects the first argument to be a `Symbol`, not a `String`:

```
Select[names, ValueQ]
(* {} *)
```

This fails (with lots of messages), because `ValueQ` doesn't evaluate the argument enough:

```
Cases[names, st_ /; ValueQ[Symbol[st]]]
(* {"abc1", "abc2", "abc3"} *)
```

If we force evaluation, we go too far, and this fails because we get `ValueQ[5]` instead of `ValueQ[abc2]`:

```
Cases[names, st_ /; ValueQ[Evaluate[Symbol[st]]]]
(* {} *)
```

**This approach works,**  but is far from elegant:

```
Cases[names, st_ /; ToExpression["ValueQ[" <> st <> "]"]]
(* "abc2" *)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I usually use

```
ToExpression["symbol",  InputForm, ValueQ]
```

ToExpression will wrap the result in its 3rd argument before evaluating it.

---

Generally, all functions that extract parts (`Extract`, `Level`, etc.) have such an argument.  This is useful when extracting parts of held expressions.  `ToExpression` acts on strings or boxes, but both the problem with evaluation control and the solution is the same.  I thought this was worth mentioning here.

Comment: Note that `ValueQ` is not innocent - it leaks evaluation. Here is some discussion, where I also contributed an answer with what is supposed to be a safer version of `valueQ` based on one-step evaluation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599241/checking-if-a-symbol-is-defined/4621562#4621562. It is overly complex, I know it can be written better, but the point is to be wary of the system `ValueQ`, to avoid nasty surprises.

Comment: @Leonid I think `ValueQ` is safe for as long as it's acting on a symbol only (i.e. is looking at `OwnValues`), but it evaluates the argument for anything else.  Is this correct?  I remember I looked at the implementation of `ValueQ` once (it's accessible) and concluded this, but that was a long time ago.

Comment: Yes, I think I came to the same conclusions. Actually, in the linked SO discussion, I give some explicit example where it leaks evaluation. Can not dig in deeper now, need to get some sleep :). But for `OwnValues` only, there is a bullet-proof solution: `(HoldComplete[sym]/.OwnValues[sym])=!=HoldComplete[sym]` - very simple and robust.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `MakeExpression`

```
ValueQ @@ MakeExpression["abc2"]
```

Answer (score 2):

This one is a different method to access symbol names and values (I think it originates from MathGroup):

(**edited** to fit the original question)

```
Attributes[symbolToRule] = {HoldAll, Listable};
symbolToRule[sym_String] := HoldForm[sym] -> Head[Symbol[sym]] =!= Symbol;
symbolToRule[sym_Symbol] := HoldForm[sym] -> ValueQ[sym];
```

with symbols:

```
{a, b = 5, c};
rules = symbolToRule[{a, b, c}]
Pick[First /@ rules, Last /@ rules]
```

output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with strings:

```
rules = symbolToRule[{"a", "b", "c"}]
Pick[First /@ rules, Last /@ rules]
```

output:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ah, but you're using `{a,b,c}` instead of `{"a","b","c"}`.  That's the tricky part... :-)

Comment: Ah, I see. Trying to cover this up cleverly...

Comment: @IstvánZachar pretty neat approach. +1 !