# Matching All Functions

Tags: pattern-matching, pure-function

Is there any way to match all functions? There's an existing answer for matching functions of one parameter (`_@_`) but it doesn't work for trying to test if a symbol is a function.

<s>Does testing if a symbol has any downvalues work?</s> Downvalue checking does not work. I would like to match all of the following:

`f`, in `f=(#)&`

`f`, in `f[x_]=x`

`(#)&` itself.

Comment: `_Function` matches a pure function, is this what you want?

Comment: Mm, it seems not, because for some reason Mathematica doesn't implement functions the way it does everything else, with substitutions. Evaluating a function name just gives you the function name, not the function body. >.<

Comment: When you say "pure functions", do you mean objects that have `Function` as the `Head`, or do you mean `f` in, say `f[x_] := x^2`? Because `MatchQ[#&, _Function]` returns `True`.

Comment: Ideally, I mean "functions before application". Given `f=(#^2)&`;, I'd like to match both `f` and `(#^2)&`.

Honestly it sounds like I might just want to try applying it to something... or check its downvalues, that's the other obvious solution.

Comment: Downvalues does not do what I want. "Try applying it and see if it evaluates nontrivally" is my current solution.

Comment: I'm still confused. If `f = # &`, then both `MatchQ[f, _Function]` and `MatchQ[#&, _Function]` evaluate to `True`. Perhaps you should explain your use case and give a couple of examples in your post.

Comment: `f[x_]=3x` doesn't, though. I'll edit in a bit more information, but it's basically what it sounds like - I want to match anything that can be applied. Ideally I'd also like to ensure that it only has one variable, too.

Comment: This looks like you're doing too much work for your problem. Consider explaining your *actual problem* that led you to consider this.

Comment: In all honesty, I don't strictly have one. I'm just being a paranoid good-practice programmer that wants to check that whatever's been passed to my second-order function is actually a function and not who knows what so I can give intelligent error messages.

Comment: In order to match objects with `Function` as the head, use what I did above. It seems like checking `DownValues` for all other cases should work (if not, give an example where it doesn't). So, wouldn't a combination of `MatchQ[expr, _Function]` and checking `DownValues` for everything else work?

Comment: Turns out, it doesn't. In particular, it doesn't work for `NumericFunction`s. Adding that seems to work, however!

Comment: Related: [(1474)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1474/121),
[(3414)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3414/121),
[(4343)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4343/121), [(59938)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59938/121)

Comment: linkhyrule5, I saw that this question was one vote from being closed by community votes.  I chose to act to close it as a duplicate instead as I think this linking is more useful.  I also posted lists to several related questions in a comment above; I encourage you to read them.  If after this you feel that your question has been marginalized let me know.